# Javascript Form validation not working on any fields

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

Below is form validation using JavaScript but it's not working.

```
function validate()
{
    var n=document.frm.name.value();
    if(!n.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/))
    {
    alert("Enter valid Name");
    document.frm.name.value="";
    document.frm.name.focus();
    return false;
    }

    var b=document.frm.mob.value();
    if(!b.match(/^[0-9]+$/) || b.length<10 || b.length>10)
    {
    alert("Enter valid Name");
    document.frm.mob.value="";
    document.frm.mob.focus();
    return false;   
    }

    var y=document.frm.nn.value();
    if(y==null || y=="")
    {
    alert("Enter valid Name");
    document.frm.nn.value="";
    document.frm.nn.focus();
    return false;   
    }

    var z=document.frm.email.value();
    if(!z.match(/^[\w\-\.\+]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-z0-9]{2,4}$/))
    {
    alert("Enter valid Name");
    document.frm.email.value="";
    document.frm.email.focus();
    return false;   
    }
}


<body>
<form name="frm" action="#" method="post" onsubmit="return validate()">
Name :<input type="text" name="name"/>
Mobile No:<input type="text" name="mob" />
Not Null :<input type="text" name="nn"/>
Email Id:<input type="text" name="email"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: (b.length<10 || b.length>10) Why can't you replace it with (b.length !== 10)

Comment: ya it's 1000% right i will do that

Answer (score 0):

First off, don't name your fields with reserved words (like "name")

Second, value is a property, not a method, so,

```
var b=document.frm.mob.value;
```

(without the brackets)

Comment: ya thats the problem thank you thank you very much i wans just tooo confuse .......tell me if any suggestion about validation please

Comment: I agree to you that this should not be preferred but I hope that do not create a problem otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Please,place return false outside the function.

```
         var b=document.frm.mob.value;
        if(!b.match(/^[0-9]+$/) || b.length<10 || b.length>10)
        {
        alert("Enter valid Name");
        document.frm.mob.value="";
        document.frm.mob.focus();     
        }

        var y=document.frm.nn.value;
        if(y==null || y=="")
        {
        alert("Enter valid Name");
    document.frm.nn.value="";
    document.frm.nn.focus();

    }

    var z=document.frm.email.value();
    if(!z.match(/^[\w\-\.\+]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-z0-9]{2,4}$/))
    {
    alert("Enter valid Name");
    document.frm.email.value="";
    document.frm.email.focus();

    }
    return false;  
}
```

Comment: how can you place the return false value outside the if loops, everytime it will return false and form will not be submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling the function **validate()** in form tag on event **onsubmit**, better use it in submit button

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" onClick="return validate()" />
```

It will work better and outputs as required.